# Android Button to change view

Tags: java, android

I have a problem I cant get my head around, I am fairly new to android and I am struggling with a basic concept of using a button to change the layout view. I have my activity Main as so

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:background="@color/bg"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >

<DigitalClock
    android:id="@+id/DigitalClock"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="100dp"

    android:textColor="#ffffff"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:textSize="70sp" />


<View 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="3dp"
    android:background="@color/line"
    />

 <Button
 android:id="@+id/AddAlarm"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
 android:text="@string/add_button"
  />


   <Button
 android:id="@+id/AddAlarm2"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
 android:text="@string/add_button"
 />
```

I can make the AddAlarm button open the add_alarm layout. But when I have opened add_alarm There is a button on that view that I need to open add_alarm2, but it wont work Here is my MainActivity.java :

```
package com.example.emma;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu; 
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.Window;
import android.widget.Button; 
import android.widget.DigitalClock;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    DigitalClock dc = (DigitalClock) findViewById(R.id.DigitalClock);



       final Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.AddAlarm);
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {

                setContentView(R.layout.add_alarm);

            }
        });



         final Button button1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.AddAlarm2);
            button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(View v) {

                    setContentView(R.layout.add_alarm2); 

                }
            });

 }

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

}
```

I kind of understand how to use a button click to change the view but I am obviously doing something wrong. Here is my add_alarm2 layout code. But when you click the imagebutton  android:id="@+id/AddAlarm2" It does nothing instead of opening the view add_alarm2.xml  Any help would be greadly appreciated

here is my add_alarm2.xml file :

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:background="@color/bg" 
tools:context=".MainActivity" >

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/AddAlarm2"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:background="@null"
    android:src="@drawable/normal"
    android:scaleType="fitCenter"
   />

<View
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="1dp"
    android:background="@color/line"
    />


</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Maybe you should use ViewFlipper or ViewSwitcher.

Answer (score 0):

a quick and dirty way to do is to put the view you wanna display inside the activity_main.xml **BUT** with *visibility=GONE*. Use the *view.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE)*;

Then when you click on the Button, you toggle the visibility of this element to VISIBLE. setContentView should be only used only one time in the onCreate(), multiple calls of it might give unexpected results.

A nicer way, would be to explore other alternative like the [ViewSwitcher](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ViewSwitcher.html), it will make the code cleaner.